# Check for the existence of inbuilt MATLAB functions in a script

Tags: matlab, function

For example I ask in a question to write a function to take in an input which is a vector and return a scaler which is the sum of all the vector elements. This can be done using for loops.
But let's say I don't want someone to use the inbuilt function **sum**. How do I check if a specific .m file contains inbuilt functions like **sum** or **max**?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If you want to check if a certain name `name` refers to a built-in function in your current path, use `exist( 'name', 'file' ) == 5`.

If you want to list all the built-in dependencies within a matlab file, use the second output of `depfun`. For example if I want to check if file `foo.m` uses the built-in function `bar`, I could do:

```
[~,builtin_dep] = depfun('foo.m','-quiet');
ismember( 'bar', builtin_dep )
```